# Trying to write a program that counts the amount of even numbers in an array and returns the value

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that will count the number of even numbers in the provided arrays. When I run the program now, it will return the amount of numbers in the array, but not the amount of even numbers. For some reason my count_even function doesn't work. Can anyone help?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int data_array_1[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 };
    int data_array_2[] = { 2, -4, 6, -8, 10, -12, 14, -16 };
    int data_array_3[] = { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
    int data_array_4[] = { 6, 2, 4, 5, 1, -9 };
    int data_array_5[] = { 1, 3, 9, 23, 5, -2, 4 };

    int result_1 = count_even(data_array_1, 6);

    printf("data_array_1 has %d even numbers.\n", result_1);

    int result_2 = count_even(data_array_2, 8);

    printf("data_array_2 has %d even numbers.\n", result_2);

    int result_3 = count_even(data_array_3, 11);

    printf("data_array_3 has %d even numbers.\n", result_3);

    int result_4 = count_even(data_array_4, 6);

    printf("data_array_4 has %d even numbers.\n", result_4);

    int result_5 = count_even(data_array_5, 7);

    printf("data_array_5 has %d even numbers.\n", result_5);


    return 0;
}

int count_even(int* data_array, int size)
{
    int even_num = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i == size; i++)
    {
        if (data_array[size] % 2 == 0)
        {
            even_num++;
        }
    }

    return even_num;
}
```

Comment: `data_array[size]` should really be `data_array[i]` and `i==size` you may want `i<size`.

Comment: Side note: You should add a declaration of `count_even` before `main`.

Comment: Your loop will never run. For example, when will `0 == 6` ever be true?

Comment: Thank you so much @bkVnet for your quick response. My code works perfectly now.

Comment: change the  for `(int i = 0; i == size; i++)` to 1 for `(int i = 0; i < size; i++)` and `if (data_array[size] % 2 == 0)` to `if (data_array[i] % 2 == 0)`

Answer (score 2):

The condition in your for loop is wrong. 
The correct condition should say "as long as the index is smaller than size",  but yours say "as long as the index equal to to size".

The condition should be `i < size`.

As for the result,  it seems like it should return 0 (for the non-working code),  not `size`.

Also,  you are using `size` as an index,  when you should use `i`.

Answer (score 0):

In your count_even function, you are using the size attribute as the array index, when it should be i

```
int count_even(int* data_array, int size)
{
    int even_num = 0
    for(int i = 0; i <= size, ++i)
    {
        if(data_array[i] % 2 == 0) 
        {
            even_num++;
        }
    }
    return even_num;
}
```

Comment: `i<=size` might lead to access the memory out of array as i=0

Answer (score 0):

these two lines are the root of the problems in the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i == size; i++)
{
    if (data_array[size] % 2 == 0)
```

the `for()` statement, should be:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

so the loop exits when reaching the end of the array

the `if()` statement is always looking at the same entry beyond the end of the array, This is undefined behaviour

The `if()` statement should be:

```
if (data_array[i] % 2 == 0)
```

However, the modulo operator `&` is not a good choice for negative numbers

a better choice would be:

```
if ( !(data_array[i] & 1 ) )
```